# Bootstrap-Table - Load json file with a link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a table loaded with a default json file using plugin bootstrap-table.

This the html code:

```
<p><a href="#">This link load another json file in the table, for example data-table-alert2.json</a></p>
<table id="table-alert1" class="table table-striped" data-sort-order="desc" data-sort-name="field3">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field1</th>
            <th>Field2</th>
            <th data-field="field3" data-sortable="true">Field3</th>
            <th data-field="field4" data-sortable="true">Field4<br />de Alerta</th>
            <th data-field="field5" data-sortable="true">Field5</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Field6</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Field7</th>
            <th>Field8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                        
</table>
```

This is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table-alert1").bootstrapTable({ 
        url: 'json/data-table-alert1.json',
        columns: [{
            field: 'col1'
        }, {
            field: 'col2'
        }, {
            field: 'col3'
        }, {
            field: 'col4'
        }, {
            field: 'col5'
        }, {
            field: 'col6'
        }, {
            field: 'col7'
        }, {
            field: 'col8'
        }, {
            field: 'col9'   
        }, {
            field: 'col10'  
        }, {
            field: 'col11'  
        }, {
            field: 'col12'  
        }, {
            field: 'col13'  
        }, {
            field: 'col14'  
        }, {
            field: 'col15'  
        }, {
            field: 'col16'          
        }, ]
    });
});
```

I need that when I click on a link or button, another file json is loaded.

Thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `refresh` method to do what you want:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    $table.bootstrapTable('refresh', {
        url: 'data-table-alert2.json'
    });
});
```

Here is an example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#issues/409.html, and the source in [GitHub](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/issues/409.html).

BTW: you can discuss this issue in: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/409.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:
First, the Json is simply not valid. You always need to give in string as parameters, like: 
      {"field" : "col1"} 
etc.

You can validate your JSON on the jsonlint.com site!

For more information you have to wait. I must leave now!

Comment: I have published the jquery call function, but not  the content json, because is correct, i have tested in the jsonlint.com site.

I relied on http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#via-javascript-table for the call function

Thanks,